# AppTransaction.shared failing on iOS 17

Tags: ios, storekit, ios17, storekit2

I noticed on iOS 17 that calling `AppTransaction.shared` fails with following errors. Here is the code:

```
       let result: VerificationResult<AppTransaction> = try await AppTransaction.shared
            
       NSLog("Result \(result)")
```

It does not hit the `NSLog` statement and instead throws the following error logs.

```
Error getting app transaction: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "(null)"   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x281815050 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=301 "Invalid    Status Code" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Status Code, AMSURL=https://mzstorekit-sb.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/receipts/createAppReceipt?REDACTED, AMSStatusCode=401, AMSServerPayload={
errorCode = 500317;
}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The response has an invalid status code}}}
 Received error that does not have a corresponding StoreKit Error:
 Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=301 "Invalid Status Code" UserInfo= {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Status Code, AMSURL=https://mzstorekit-   sb.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/receipts/createAppReceipt?REDACTED, AMSStatusCode=401,  AMSServerPayload={
errorCode = 500317;
}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The response has an invalid status code}
Received error that does not have a corresponding StoreKit Error:
Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "(null)" UserInfo=.{NSUnderlyingError=0x281815050 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=301 "Invalid Status Code" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Status Code, AMSURL=https://mzstorekit-sb.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/receipts/createAppReceipt?REDACTED, AMSStatusCode=401, AMSServerPayload={
errorCode = 500317;
}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The response has an invalid status code}}}
```